# Proof of finite expectation of renewal process (2)

Tags: stochastic-processes

I don't know if it is allowed here, to repost again his own question. I hope it is ok... I already asked this question here: [Finite expectation of renewal process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731141/finite-expectation-of-renewal-process/752766#752766)
But I don't understand the last steps and I didn't get any answer in 4 months... And I really want to understand it! I post again all here:

Let $T_n$ be a random variable with $T_n=X_1+...+X_n$ where the $X_i$'s are iid. Further we set $N(t)=max\{ n: T_n\leq t\}$ with the property $\Pr(N(t)<\infty)=1$.

> Claim: $\mathbb{E}[N(t)]<\infty$.

Proof:

I define a new renewal process $\{\bar N(t), t\geq 0\}$ with interarrival times $\bar X_n$. Let $\alpha$ be a positive number:
\begin{equation}
\bar X_n=\begin{cases}
0 \text{ if } X_n<\alpha\\
\alpha \text{ if } X_n\geq\alpha
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and $\bar N(t)=\sup\{n: \bar X_1+\bar X_2+...+\bar X_n\leq t\}$.

So the new renewal process has a gap between the renewals only if the original process has an interarrival time larger than $\alpha$. If one draws a sample path for the original and the new process, then it is obvious that the new process has renewals only at times $t=\alpha n$. From the drawing it follows also that the number of renewals in an arbitrary interval $(k\alpha, (k+1)\alpha]$ is geometric distributed with $p=P(X_n\geq \alpha)$. Hence the expected number of renewals in the interval is $1/P(X_n\geq \alpha)$:
$$\mathbb{E}[\bar N(t)]=\frac{1}{P(X_n\geq \alpha)}.$$
Since $N(t) \leq \bar N(t)$, we have $\mathbb{E}[ N(t)] \leq \mathbb{E}[\bar N(t)]$.

But unfortunately I don't know how can I conclude that $\frac{1}{P(X_n\geq \alpha)}<\infty$... Can anybody help me out here? I appreciate any help, idea or advice!

Comment: This IS a dup. // Answer: One **chooses** $\alpha\gt0$ small enough such that $P(X_1\geqslant\alpha)\ne0$ (and this can be done for every almost surely nonnegative $X_1$, except if $P(X_1=0)=1$).

Comment: ah yess!! Thank you very very much! I got it!! And sorry for the duplicate! I wrote it in my question, I didn't know that this is forbidden...